# Sortable List for Metro App - Examples/Ideas?

Tags: metro, windows-8, listview

I'm building a Metro App that lists all your Facebook and twitter likes on a per URL basis.

So it's basically just a list. But I think the usual Metro Tiles/Grid style is really not very helpful here. This is how the App looks right now, just to give you an idea about the data:

[Super Social Media Tracker](http://apptivate.ms/apps/1276/super-social-media-tracker)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Screenshots**.

They'd add visual appeal and might add functionality as well. I can tell from a screenshot which page on my site is being referenced more quickly than I can scan the URL.

A visual way to browse popularity by screenshots could be interesting. http://pttrns.com is a site about design patterns, but the overall style (big pictures, minimal text) fits with Microsoft's "modern" aesthetic.

[image: Design patterns]

- **Default sorting options could be useful**.

For example, "most popular" could aggregate the Facebook and Twitter likes and then display the URLs in order of most liked to least liked.

- **Visualization of changes over time**.

Microsoft's finance app shows one minimal, tile-y concept for a way to display increases and decreases over time.

[image: Microsoft Finance app]

Answer (score 2):

The tradicional Windows Grid is not recommended for that use. There's a guideline for search purposes:

**Start app page**
[image]

**You can use auto suggest, but filter should be placed with the results**

Here's an example of how your results list could be.

[image]

**Kinda like this**

[image]

For more Windows guidelines info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465233.aspx

Comment: It's _not_ called Metro any more.